# Using cmd to set Application to default

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sccm

When I am deploying the new application for Adobe Reader DC Continuous, it uninstalls the older version and installs the new version. I understand that I can just deploy the patch instead of uninstalling and installing again, but the norm of my team is to uninstall and install. So when I uninstall it, all PDF files now open with Microsoft Edge. I need to set it back to Adobe Reader once the new Adobe Reader has been installed.

The steps I have done include: exporting my default application XML, editing it, and put it in a file called DefaultAppAssoc.xml and I call this on my deployment install batch file through `Dism.exe /online /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:DefaultAppAssoc.xml`. It says the operation is successful, but when I reboot my computer, the files still are set to open with Edge.

When I use cmd, `assoc .pdf` the result is `.pdf=AcroExch.Document.DC` when I try `ftype acroExch.Document.DC` the result is `acroExch.Document.DC="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "%1"`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the association with the `ftype` command?

Comment: afaik the only programmatic way to set associations in win10 is wie gpo and xml and then it's permanent (user can never change it again). is this an option? dism will only affect new profiles and assoc does not really work anymore. There is however the possibility to prevent edge from ever taking back the pdf association. here's a guide how to do this (https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/edge-hijack-pdf-htm-associations/) I am not sure if this will really be enough to mitigate your problem. If it does tell me and I will reformulate this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this for weeks, and I would like to thank Syberdoor for his answer and the registry hack link.

With Windows 10 Pro, Version 20H2, OS Build 19042.1288, I have installed an older version of Adobe Reader, because I don't like the current with bells and whistles.  However, Microsoft Edge would always hijack the PDF association no matter how many times I set it back to Adobe Reader.

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/edge-hijack-pdf-htm-associations/

The registry edit at the above link still worked on Version 20H2.  Rebooted a few times to make sure and Adobe Reader is locked in.  BTW, I did not need to go to his 2019 Update link for Version 20H2.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30270824)